# How do I caption a Table across multiple pages in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a table that is multiple pages long in Word.  I'd like to have the caption associated with it to be at the top of each page so that the reader doesn't forget which table they are reading.  How can I do this within Word without breaking the Table of Tables and linking?

Answer (score 0):

Select the first line of the table, and right click and chose 'repeat this line on every page'

Answer (score 0):

I had a macro that automatically added a caption to the first row of the table. Unfortunately, the macro does not work with Word 360.

You can get the same effect by creating your caption, then dragging into the first row of your table (merge cells). If you set that as a repeating row along with your column headers, it will repeat on every page thereafter.